# Is there a safe way to open a possibly spam facebook attachment?

Tags: spam, facebook

I got a spam attachment from two of my facebook friends
I know it is spam because of the nature of the content
I also know that these aren't the type of people to send such a message to me deliberately, so I am sure they ran some kind of script while being logged in to facebook
The message has a zip file attachment, and I would like to see what happens if I click it
I am fine with it downloading some unsafe zip file to my computer, since I will be doing it in a virtual machine anyway
But I have been told by others that it is possible to run scripts on facebook just by clicking a link (for example, if I click a link something gets posted on my wall that has all of my friends tagged in it). Is this true? Personally I don't believe it should be possible, but I am not sure and would like some confirmation (for example, I don't want a simple clicking of that attachment to send automated messages to all my contacts. Malware file being downloaded is fine though)

Alternatively, is it possible to forward a facebook private message? Or somehow open that attachment without logging in to facebook, or get it to download from a different account?

PS: This spam is either very new or not very popular, as searching the name of the zip file in google does not give any results (or perhaps the zip file has been generated with a random name may be?)

This is what the message looks like:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont know if this would work, but if you look at the source code of your facebook message page, you might be able to identify the download link of the attachment so you can then open it when you are not logged into facebook. Additionally, you could always download it without unzipping it (you are in a VM already) and then open it in some forensic suite like FTK imager to view the source code of the malware itself.

Answer (score 1):

> But I have been told by others that it is possible to run scripts on facebook just by clicking a link (for example, if I click a link something gets posted on my wall that has all of my friends tagged in it). Is this true?

Lookup Cross Site Request Forgery. I imagine Facebook takes a number of steps to prevent this kind of thing though.

Downloading the file should not be a problem if it is hosted by Facebook. If it is hosted on a 3rd party site you run the risk of landing on a malicious webpage which will then redirect you to the download once it has done its mischief.

I suggest opening the zip file inside a virtual machine with no Internet access. If it turns out to be suspicious then consider burning the VM or restoring it to a previous snapshot.

Comment: The file seems to be hosted by facebook as the link seems to point to 'h t t p s : / / www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/attachment.php?attach_id...' followed by some gibberish. My main concern is something else happening automatically if I click the link, instead of the file being downloaded

Answer (score 1):

These programs typically make use of the fact that you were already authenticated to Facebook, so it does not need to steal your credentials as it already has access to your account. It is the same principle as you opening up your browser and already being logged into facebook.

If you run this from within a VM that you have not logged into facebook through then you should be good. Just remember, you do not exactly know what was in the malicious file so consider the entire VM to be compromised, as such reset it back to its original state once you are done with the malware.

Comment: Note he may need to be logged into facebook in order to download the attachment…

Answer (score 0):

""But I have been told by others that it is possible to run scripts on facebook just by clicking a link (for example, if I click a link something gets posted on my wall that has all of my friends tagged in it). Is this true? ""

I know one time I clicked on a video link on facebook, nothing happened apparently but some unethical posts were posted up on my wall without my knowledge. I investigated the situation only to find out that an unknown extension(malicious) got downloaded in my browser and it was actually posting on my behalf as I was logged in. So yup it's possible.

P.S I'm not an English

Comment: Which web browser were you using? What extension was installed?